# Memory optimization when assigning NSString to UILabel text

Tags: ios, nsstring, uilabel

In my view, I have a `UILabel` which text property is updated every second.

```
- (void)updateLabelWithValue:(NSInteger)value
{
    self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", value];
}
```

Isn't this costly memory wise? It creates a new `NSString` every time. Is there a way to just have one `NSString` instance and update its text?

Thanks

Comment: Run it through the allocations tool.

Answer (score 2):

You're worrying too much about a very very minor optimization. Yes, you're creating a new instance of `NSString` on every pass, but you're also destroying the old one, so in essence you're replacing the string.